# Cannot find module import node 13 typescript webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to get a http websocket typescript server using node 13 running but I can't get the server to boot due to this error:

```
(node:8118) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:94
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^

Error: Cannot find module /Users/mmo19/Documents/projects/planning-poker/http-server imported from /Users/mmo19/Documents/projects/planning-poker/server.ts
```

I am currently importing 
`/Users/mmo19/Documents/projects/planning-poker/http-server`

as `import app from './http-server';`

I have tried importing using `import * as app from './http-server'` however i still get the same error.

I have tried running with `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node --experimental-modules` flags but still have the same error.

[An image of my file structure layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0eEC.png)

Here is my ts.config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "jsx": "react",
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config:

```
'use-strict';
module.exports = {
    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
        modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
loader'.
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    externals: {
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    },
};
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "game-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint '*/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --inline --config webpack.config.cjs",
    "server": "tsc && node server.ts",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.cjs"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "ws": "^7.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.6",
    "@types/ws": "^7.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a few days and only been able to see ways around this using the `--experimentals-module` flag which doesn't seem to work... any direction would be really appreciated!

Comment: What node version are you using? "type": "module" wasn't supported in previous versions

Comment: Hello, I'm using node 13.2